# Getting PHP Variable from Page to the Other

Tags: php, session

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

On one page, I start a session close to the beginning of the start of the code, like this:

```
session_name('raprec');
session_start();
```

And then I collect the session variables throughout the code by assigning session variables to the PHP variables I need to reuse, as follows:

```
    $_SESSION['item_type'] = $item_type;
    $_SESSION['special_rope_fields'] = $special_rope_fields;
    $_SESSION['zoom_obj'] = $zoom_obj;
```

On the second page, where I need the items I call the session again:

```
session_start();
session_name('raprec');
```

Then I try to use them on this second page, as follows:

```
$special_rope_fields = $_SESSION['special_rope_fields'];
$item_type = $_SESSION['item_type'];
$zoom_obj = $_SESSION['zoom_obj'];
```

But it doesn't work...

I try to see if anything is in them like this:

```
print_r($_SESSION['special_rope_fields']);
print_r($_SESSION['item_type']);
print_r($_SESSION['zoom_obj']);
```

But nothing appears.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I properly pass these variables from one page to the next? Is there an easier way, perhaps?

Comment: make sure you call `session_start` at the very beginning of each script. Check your PHP log for warnings about headers sent after output.

Comment: can you try it withough session_name, also you dont need to start it a second time, this will throw a warning, are you sure this is teh same application?  because that will be a problem.  i.e if your running two different php files, then you might be running two different apps.  what does the first ,and second page look like?

Answer (score 2):

I've tested your code on my server and I had the exact same results as you, nothing... then, on the **`second page`**, I've changed:

```
session_start();
session_name('raprec');
```

to

```
session_name('raprec');
session_start();
```

The session `raprec` now works as intended.

---

[NOTE:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php#42747)

> the `session_name()` function will have no essential effect if you set
>   `session.auto_start` to `true` in `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

per this documentation, http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php you need to call session_start after you call session_name.

edit
@maztch sorry, i updated.  thanks for pointing that out.  i had it backwards, but thats what i meant, i was trying to point out that the doc has a specific order... thanks. and in this case its not an answer at all is it, because it doesnt address the question now after all.  oops..

Comment: Sorry, but at doc says exactly the opposite. session_name must be set before session_sart